# How to see if checkboxes with the same name are checked and then retrieve the values in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a list of songs. I'm trying to determine whether or not a song on the list has been checked or not. If so I need to know the value of the checkbox.

my html looks like this... the value $song_id is pulled from the list in the database.

`<input type='checkbox' name='song[]' value='$song_id' />`

There could be 10 songs... there could 100.
I need to know which ones have been checked and how to get the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach ( $_POST['song'] AS $song_id ) {
    // do smth with $song_id ...
}
```

Comment: This is giving me a result close to what I was looking for... thank you so much.

Comment: People are giving good valid responses, but it's all front end. This so far is the only thing that allows me to get the information through php. Of course, I'm a bit of noob, so maybe I'm just not understanding. Thanks to all that have offered assistance. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. On click save item ID of item to array; (js)
2. On click search was such ID already checked; (in array)

ADDED

You should use jQuery (or raw javascript) to do logic you want. jQuery is http://jquery.com/ using it you can do you want on front-end. Do this on back-end is bad idea.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Because there are two cases to deal with it, on front and back-end. This one should be done in front-end. Of course you can do it using php (back-end), but it won't be right. (It's all about architecture of site developing)

Comment: Ok... forgive me for being a noob and all... but I need it on the backend because I'm trying to submit this information to a database.... so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you submit the form the `$_POST['song']` variable will contain an array of all the `$song_id`'s that were selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='song[]' class='songItem' value='$song_id' />
<input type='hidden' id='selectSongsHidden' />
```

In JavaScript,

```
var selectedSongValues = [];
var selectedSongsString = ""; // for comma-separated values
function GetSelectedSongs()
{
    var songs = $('.songItem');
    var selectedSongs = [];
    for(var i=0; i<songs.length; i++)
    {
         var checked = $(songs[i]).is(':checked');
         if(checked)
         {
              selectedSongs.push(songs[i]);
         }
    }
    for(var j=0; j<selectedSongs.length; j++)
    {
         selectedSongValues.push($(selectedSongs[j]).val());
         selectedSongsString += $(selectedSongs[j]).val() + ",";
    }
    $('#selectSongsHidden').val(selectedSongsString);
}
```

When you press submit, in the onclick event you can call this function and set the value to a hidden field.

You can see this in a working http://jsfiddle.net/A3e3y

Comment: when you press the submit button, you can take the value from selectedSongsString and store it in a hidden field and send it to the server. In the server you can split the values.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try... so after the hidden field is submitted do I split it on the back end with a spit() function?

Comment: you can make use of the explode function to split the string into an array

Comment: Ok.... thanks. I'm gonna give it a try. I wish I could put both of your answers as the preferred one.

Comment: well you can try and if still not then you can always upvote the answer :)